# Linux Tiling window manager that works well within VMware (resolution, monitor changes)

Tags: linux, vmware-workstation

I tried to use awesome within VMware, but I'd like to use the ability to change the resolution by resizing the window, and cycling through different multi-monitor modes.

Gnome deals with this fine, but awesome doesn't, though I'm unsure how much help Gnome has from VMware Tools.

Is there one that does work well in this scenario?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've just noticed that running vmware-user after starting awesome will solve that issue. I don't know if it's okay for multiple monitors but at least it scales to the right resolution.

It can take a few secondes before resizing the screen, it's not smooth as unity or gnome are.

Comment: Super, that does indeed work. But cycling multiple monitors does not. It also seems to reset awesome everytime there is a resize, i.e. you go to workspace 1 and all workspaces lose the tiling mode to which they are set.